# Static method to return a singleton spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, static, autowired

Trying to build a task executor app in spring boot. The idea is to design a template to retrieve the default TaskConfig so that executor can just execute it.

```
@Component
public class TaskExecutor {

private final TaskTemplate taskTemplate;

@Autowired
public TaskExecutor(TaskTemplate taskTemplate) {
    this.taskTemplate=taskTemplate;
}

public void runTask() {
final TaskConfiguration taskConfig = taskTemplate.getTaskConfig("taskName");
  taskConfig.do();
  }
}

@Component
public class TaskTemplate {
private final TaskParam1 taskParam1;
private final TaskParam2 taskParam2;

@Autowired
public TaskTemplate(TaskParam1 taskParam1, TaskParam2 taskParam2) {
    this.taskParam1 = taskParam1;
    this.taskParam2 = taskParam2;
}

public TaskConfiguration getTaskConfig() {
// Logic to build the task configuration from task template params
 }
}
```

The problem I see is that the TaskTemplate is coupled with the TaskExecutor (Autowired), which I wish to remove.
I wanted to replace it with a static convenient method to return the singleton Template so that I could execute the getTaskConfig with it.

Looking for suggestion to improve upon this.

Thanks

Comment: Its not really clear what problem you have.

Comment: @Deadron I am trying to avoid the coupling between TaskExecutor and TaskTemplate. I wanted to get rid of constructor injection, instead get the template bean by some static factory kindof methods

Comment: The fact that you are injecting tasktemplate is already an example of loose coupling. Injection and static factory methods both serve the same purpose conceptually and swapping from one to the other makes no substantial difference.  You should actually tell us what your problem is and why you think you need to change it.

Comment: Looking at this, I got a feel that it needs to have a tasktemplate for creating a taskexecutor bean which is not right. TaskTemplate is meant to be an alternate way of creating task configurations.

Comment: So I’m trying to avoid dependency injection, looking for an alternate approach to get the same with some static method calls

Answer (score -1):

You can inject ApplicationContext to another bean like below code. After spring initialized you can use BeanGetter.getTaskTemplate() to get TaskTemplate singleton bean.

```java
...
final TaskConfiguration taskConfig = BeanGetter.getTaskTemplate().getTaskConfig("taskName");
...
```

```java
@Service
public class BeanGetter {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    
    @Autowired
    public BeanGetter(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static TaskTemplate getTaskTemplate(){
        return applicationContext.getBean(TaskTemplate.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just looking for a solution wherein I can call a static in template itself